# Ionic Push: GCM project number not found in android application

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-cloud-messaging, ionic.io

I'm trying to use `ionic.io` to send push notification. Here is what I did :

1. Create an app in GCM and enable GCM API.

[image]

2. Create credentials and get the api key.

[image]

3. Create an app in ionic.io dashboard
4. Create a security profile and add the api key

[image]

5. Create an api token in `ionic.io` dashboard

[image]

6. My source code in app.js which generated by **ionic start pushdemo**

   ```
   .run(function($ionicPlatform) {

   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

   var push = new Ionic.Push({
     "debug": true
   });

   push.register(function(token) {
     alert(token.token);
     console.log("Device token:",token.token);
     push.saveToken(token);
   });
   ```

7.Add push plugin:

> ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable
>   SENDER_ID="myproject_number"

I tried both with or without quotation mark around **myproject_number**. It's the project number in step 1.

8.Set the **dev_push** to false

9.Hook my app to ionic.io by **ionic io init**

10.Run **ionic run android -lc**

Found the following error message:

[image]

What's wrong with it? Can anybody help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem its generally because of proxy issue 
you are behind the proxy it means you are using internet by making request to the server ,so first you should use your own internet (in this case if you use WIFI 
then also it will work )
second aafter creating your project dirsctly make login from your cinsole to ionic io
it will ake for email and password that will make your app live
third

```
ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="myproject_number"
```

use quotes for entering your project number.project number also called GCM number and your server  key is the key you generated in same project means google console which enable you to use google services.
 and dont forget to add android platform

Comment: also dont forget to upload after login

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm using wifi. Still got **GCM Project Number is not found**

Comment: ionic config set gcm_key   <your-gcm-project-number>

Comment: type above command and dont use this  <> just put your gcm proect number which you genereated at google console

Comment: Is gcm-project-number is something like 9748xxxxxxxx? This time I got this error: **Ionic Push:, (debug) unexpected error occured.Ionic Push:, [object Object]**

Comment: Then I don't know what happened. Apparently I input the correct GCM Project Number.

Answer (score 1):

ionic start pushCall
ionic login
ionic upload

//open google console
1-create project
2-use google api
    1-mobile APIs
    2-select google cloud messaging and eneble it
    3- go to credential and create API key

//after that add following plugin

ionic add ionic-platform-web-client
ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="991785317333"
(dont remove quotes while adding gcm number)

//add platfom

ionic platform add android
ionic io init
ionic config set dev_push true

//open ionic io
go to setting
    1-create api key
    2-go to certificate and create security profile name edit id click on android and  add GCM key
    and save it.

```
//add this code to app.js


angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
 var push = new Ionic.Push({
  "debug": true
    });

   push.register(function(token) {
  console.log("My Device token:",token.token);
  push.saveToken(token);  // persist the token in the Ionic Platform
    });
});
})
```

//to test wether your configure correctly with ionic io open launch postman
//and then do the following things:

```
1-create collection give it a valid name
2-in body click on text and select Application/json
it will add header automatically
3-add another header     
key as Authorization
value as bearer followed by your api token from ionic io
4-select "raw " as the format of our json
2-in body section of your collection write
following code
{
"tokens": ["DEV_DEVICE_TOKEN"],
    "profile": "PROFILE_NAME",
    "notification":
     {
    "message": "This is my demo push!"
     }
}
```

//now it will prompt message on browser

ionic config set gcm_key   
ionic config set dev_push false
ionic build android

install your app in mobile and send the notification from postman

(Mahesh Sampat Nighut)
navi mumbai

Comment: I'm doing almost the same as you mentioned in your answer. But my problem is **GCM Project Number is not found** although I added the number when I ```ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="myproject_number"```

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your app.js

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
     var push = new Ionic.Push({
      "debug": true
        });

       push.register(function(token) {
      console.log("My Device token:",token.token);
      push.saveToken(token);  // persist the token in the Ionic Platform
        });
    });
    })
```

and dont forget to run below command

```
ionic config set dev_push true
```

when you are testing it on browser make above cammand true,this means developmant mode ,and when you are making apk this time you have to make above command false

Comment: I have no problem to run in **limited mode** at all. But my problem is when I tried to run it in real device for production mode. Means the **dev_push** set to false.